# Remix.js Dynamic Routing dot delimiter not working

Tags: reactjs, frontend, remix

I just started looking into Remix, and I am following the Udemy tutorial.
I have come across a problem where routing is not working as expected. I have two files:
`notes.jsx` and `notes.$id.jsx` where the first is the landing page for notes, and the second will be for details, this follows the "dot delimiter" rounting concept, however, even tough I can see the url change to `notes/123` i still end up at `notes.jsx`. But if I remove the "dot" and call the second file `$id.jsx` and go to `/123` I end up at the correct file.

Here are the file structure currently:
[image]

I have read the documentation, and as mentioned followed the tutorial, but I cannot figure out why it in this case is not working.

Any advice or ideas is appriciated

I have tried converting to the folder structure that is also allowed, but without any luck. I have also tried removing the dynamic part of the rounting to see if that affects it, with similar results, I could not reach a file `notes.test.jsx` at `notes/test` as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Note that /note/test does not nest with note.tsx anymore, but root.tsx. The trailing_ underscore creates a path segment, but it does not create layout nesting.

Think of the trailing_ underscore as the long bit at the end of your parent's signature, writing you out of the will, removing the segment that follows from the layout nesting.

```
notes_.test.tsx
```

Answer (score 0):

Remix supports nested layouts. That is, you can specify, what pages share the layout.

Route named **notes.$noteId.jsx** tells Remix, that **noteId** page should share the layout specified in the **notes** route.

In this case, you should add **Outlet** component to the **notes** route.

This **Outlet** component marks the place, where the active page (the one you are currently visiting) should be injected to.

```
export default function Notes() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>This element will be shared among *notes* and *noteId* 
       pages</h3>
      <Outlet />  // noteId page will go here
    </div>
  );
}
```

If you don't want the **noteId** page to share the layout with a **note** page, just make your route notes_.$noteId.jsx

Then you won't have to add the **Outlet** component and will be able to access **noteId** page at **notes/nodeId**